# Update Google event in calendar C#

Tags: c#, html, google-calendar-api

I have a requirement where I have to add a button to the email. On clicking, it opens Google asks for credentials and then adds the event to the calendar of the user. Here is my code.

```html
<tr style="display:none;">
    <td width="300" style="width:225.0pt; background:#313131; padding:0in 0in 0in 0in; height:30.0pt; border-radius:3px">
        <p class="x_MsoNormal" align="center" style="text-align:center">
            <span style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif; color:white">
                <a href="@Model.GoogleLink" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" data-auth="NotApplicable" data-linkindex="10">
                    <span style="color:white; text-decoration:none">Add to Google Calendar</span>
                </a>
            </span>
        </p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my google link:
https://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=Piercing+Studio+Appointment+(Ossington+Piercing+Studio)&dates=20230716T202000Z/20230716T204000Z&location=64+Ossington+Avenue,+Toronto,+Ontario,+M6J2Y7&details=64+Ossington+Avenue,+Toronto,+Ontario,+M6J2Y7%0A%0AView/Change+Appointment:%0Ahttps://app.acuityscheduling.com/schedule.php?owner%3D28316543%26id%255B%255D%3D87dc83cf48dc52001b1dd5f79ce9b0ef%26action%3Dappt%0A%0A(created+by+Acuity+Scheduling)%0AAcuityID%3D1071322728%0AGoogle&sf=true&output=xml&pli=1

Is there any way to update the event if the event is already in the calendar?

PS: I am not using google-calendar-api but solution with it will also be appreciated.

Comment: In a web application, updating Google Calendar events without using Google API isn't feasible. Google API provides the necessary access and permissions for a third-party application to create, read, update, or delete events.

Comment: Alright, I have edited my original post to welcome solutions with api as well. Please note I DO NOT know users email. They should get login prompt

Comment: Understood, I will post an answer using the API.

Comment: @yousufalvi - please consider "upvoting" and "accdepting" 
Corey Sutton's reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the functionality of updating Google Calendar events from a web application, the recommended approach is to use the Google Calendar API along with OAuth 2.0 authentication. This method provides the necessary access and permissions for a third-party application to create, read, update, or delete events on the user's calendar. Updating being a keyword here for your question.

Below are the steps involved in integrating the Google Calendar API for event updates:

Set up Google API Credentials: Begin by creating a new project in the [Google Developers Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/). Enable the Google Calendar API for this project and generate OAuth 2.0 Client ID credentials for your web application. These credentials will grant the required access to manipulate events on users' calendars.

Client-side Code: Modify your existing HTML code to include the appropriate JavaScript and libraries for handling Google API calls. Implement OAuth 2.0 authentication to obtain an access token after successful user authentication. This token will allow your application to interact with the user's Google Calendar.

Event Update: When the user clicks the "Add to Google Calendar" button, initiate the OAuth 2.0 authentication process through your JavaScript code (This is where google will ask them to sign in). Once the access token is obtained, **use it to make a PATCH request to the Google Calendar API, updating the specific event's details in the request body.**

Handling User Authentication: Since you mentioned not having access to the user's email, **the OAuth 2.0 flow will handle the authentication process for you.** **Users will be prompted to log in to their Google account**, and if necessary, provide their credentials to grant the required permissions.

Please note that during the process, users might encounter the Google consent screen, which explains the permissions your application is requesting, including access to their Google Calendar. This is a standard part of the OAuth flow and ensures transparency for users and I wouldn't worry about it.

Using the Google Calendar API along with OAuth 2.0 authentication offers a more secure and reliable method to interact with users' calendars compared to attempting to manipulate events via a direct link in an email. For a more in-depth understanding of the implementation details, you can refer to the official [Google Calendar API documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api).

Comment: Excellent response.  The OP has several challenges: 1) Updating an existing Google Calendar event (the original question), 2) Querying if there *IS* an existing event, 3) Adding a new event if there isn't, and 4) "Authenticating" (to do any of the above).  He should absolutely use the .NET API, and he needs to register and configure his app to allow OAuth2.  You've covered all of these :) ADDITIONALLY: I would encourage the OP to consider [Identity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity)

Answer (score 1):

While Corey Sutton's answer is a comprehensive guide on how to approach the problem, I will provide you with a C# code example that should help you to update an event using the Google Calendar API:

```
public async Task UpdateCalendarEvent(string eventId, Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event newEvent)
{
// Initialize the client
UserCredential credential;
using (var stream = new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    string credPath = "token.json";
    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
        Scopes,
        "user",
        CancellationToken.None,
        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
}

var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
});

// Fetch the existing event
Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event existingEvent = await service.Events.Get("primary", eventId).ExecuteAsync();

// Update the necessary fields from the new event data
existingEvent.Summary = newEvent.Summary;
existingEvent.Location = newEvent.Location;
existingEvent.Description = newEvent.Description;
existingEvent.Start = newEvent.Start;
existingEvent.End = newEvent.End;

// Update the event in the calendar
var request = service.Events.Update(existingEvent, "primary", existingEvent.Id);
request.Execute();
}
```

This is a simplified version of the code to update a Google Calendar event using the Google Calendar API with C#. You need to replace "credentials.json" and "token.json" with the correct paths for your OAuth 2.0 credentials file and your token storage file, respectively. "primary" is used to refer to the primary calendar of the authenticated user. Please also define Scopes and ApplicationName as per your requirements.

As Corey Sutton mentioned, you need to use OAuth 2.0 to authenticate the user and get their permission to access and modify their Google Calendar. The Google API .NET client libraries provide the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync method to handle the authentication process. After obtaining the necessary authorization, you can use the CalendarService to interact with the user's calendar.

The service.Events.Get method is used to fetch the existing event. After updating the necessary fields, the service.Events.Update method is used to update the event in the calendar.